# Fancybox On touch screen, the single close button does not work

Tags: fancybox

On touch screen, I can close the fancybox only by using the close button from the top helper-bar, or by clicking outside the image. but not from the single close button.

sample link -
http://vasterad.com/themes/nevia/single-project.html
(click\touch the large image)

JS code - (Using fancyBox.min v2.1.3)

```
$('[rel=fancybox-gallery]').fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    nextEffect  : 'elastic',
    prevEffect  : 'elastic',

    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        },
        buttons : {},
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)'
            }
        }
    },

});
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the z-index gets messed up on the single close button on touch? I'm running into this, and at the moment I can't get safari's developer tools to run with my phone to check. I'm thinking about reassigning a custom button to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest fancy-box v2.1.5 solved the problem!